# Partial Measurement in AWS Braket

Tags: programming, amazon-braket

Is there a way to do partial Measurement in AWS Braket? Basically, if I have a circuit with $N$ qubits, can I measure only $n$ qubits out of them with the result type "expectation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physically, there is currently no way to perform a partial measurement (on hardware in particular, all qubits are measured); you'll have to slice out the unwanted qubits if you're using raw measurements directly. As for result types, you can definitely measure the expectation of an observable on only a subset of qubits:

```
from braket.circuits import Circuit, observables
from braket.devices import LocalSimulator

dev = LocalSimulator()
circ = Circuit().h(0).cnot(0, 1).cnot(1, 2).expectation(observables.Z() @ observables.Z(), [0, 2])
dev.run(circ).result().values
```

```
[1.0]
```